# Prove that $( R \circ S ) \cap T = \varnothing$ iff $(\mathrm{R}^{-1} \circ T) \cap S= \varnothing$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, inverse-function, function-and-relation-composition

I am having a bit of a hard time proving the following statement:

> Show that
>   $( R \circ S ) \cap T = \varnothing$ iff $(\mathrm{R}^{-1} \circ T) \cap S= \varnothing$.

I sort of understand composition of functions, inverse functions, and set theory individually, but when put together I seem to get confused.

It would be wonderful if anyone could be of help, as I'm not even sure how to begin.

Thank you!

EDIT: See attempt at the question in the answers

Comment: So your question is about functions?

Comment: Thank you! Would it be sufficient to, for example, let R = {a,b} and so on? I am not quite sure how I would go to prove this generally..

Comment: @CalumGilhooley Thank you for all your suggestions and help. I edited my question and added my attempt. I'm unsure of whether my proof is properly constructed, but it's all starting to make sense, finally!

Answer (score 1):

If $(R \circ S) \cap T)$ is empty, then
not exists $a,x,y$ with $xRa$ and $aSy$ and $xTy$.

If $(R^{−1} \circ T) \cap S)$ is empty, then
not exists $a,x,y$ with $aRx$ and $aTy$ and $xSy$.

Lo and behold, with a simple switch around of variables...

Comment: Thank you for you answer! Just to make sure I understand, does this mean that if the statement is empty, then there does not exist any sets which are reflexive, symmetric, or transitive, which cannot be the case?

Comment: @BumbleMii.   Statement cannot be empty .

Answer (score 1):

$( R \circ S ) \cap T = \varnothing$ iff $(\mathrm{R}^{-1} \circ T) \cap S= \varnothing \iff ( R \circ S ) \cap T \ne \varnothing$ iff $(\mathrm{R}^{-1} \circ T) \cap S \ne \varnothing$

Let R, S, T be relations on the same set  A

1. $( R \circ S ) \cap T \ne \varnothing \to (\mathrm{R}^{-1} \circ T) \cap S \ne \varnothing$

Assuming $( R \circ S ) \cap T \ne \varnothing$,

Then, $\exists x, y \in A$ such that $(x,y) \in R \circ S$ and $(x,y) \in T$

$(x,y) \in R \circ S \implies \exists z$ such that $(x,z) \in R$
and $(z,y) \in S$

$(x,z) \in R \implies (z,x) \in \mathrm{R}^{-1}$

From $(z,x) \in \mathrm{R}^{-1}$ and $(x,y) \in T$, we can say that $(z,y) \in \mathrm{R}^{-1} \circ T$

Now, from $(z,y) \in \mathrm{R}^{-1} \circ T$ and $(z,y) \in S$, we can conclude that $(z,y) \in (\mathrm{R}^{-1} \circ T) \cap S$.

2. $( R \circ S ) \cap T \ne \varnothing \leftarrow (\mathrm{R}^{-1} \circ T) \cap S \ne \varnothing$

Assuming $(\mathrm{R}^{-1} \circ T) \cap S \ne \varnothing$,

Then, $\exists x, y \in A$ such that $(x,y) \in \mathrm{R}^{-1} \circ T$ and $(x,y) \in S$

$(x,y) \in \mathrm{R}^{-1} \circ T \implies \exists z$ such that $(x,z) \in \mathrm{R}^{-1}$ and $(z,y) \in T$

$(x,z) \in \mathrm{R}^{-1} \implies (z,x) \in R$

From $(z,x) \in R$ and $(x,y) \in S$, we can say that $(z,y) \in R \circ S$

Now, from $(z,y) \in R \circ S$ and $(z,y) \in T$, we can conclude that $(z,y) \in ( R \circ S ) \cap T$.